# Python: "IndexError: string index out of range" Beginner

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

I know, I know, this question has been asked plenty of times before. But I can't figure out how to fix it here - in this particular instance. When I subtract 2, which is what was recommended, I still get the same error within if statement. Thanks 
The code (at least it should) take a string "s" and measure it against the alphabet "order" and then give an output of the longest substring in s which is in alphabetical order.

```
order = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
s = 'abcbcdabc'
match = ""

for i in range(len(s)):
for j in range(len(order)):
    if (((i + j ) - 2) < len(order) and order[i] == s[j]):
        match += s[i] 

print("Longest substring in alphabetical order is: " + match)
```

Comment: What is `s` and what is `order`? And what exactly are you trying to do? Can you summarize your problem, show an example input, and your expected output?

Comment: The code is supposed to take a string (s) and find the longest string which it has in common with another string(order) and the output is the longest matching string. I'll edit the main code with the rest of the code

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are using index `j` of `order` list to access `s` list. It is possible that `j` is greater than `len(s)` hence the `IndexError`.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve with the code. But in any case heres what you can change to make it working: `match += s[i]` OR `match += order[j]`

Comment: The issue is actually within the if statement. Sorry for not clarifying

Comment: Yes that as well. I seem to have missed that. thanks for pointing out.